# Displaying gift certificate info in Cartthrob's checkout/cart when buying a certificate

Tags: cartthrob, checkout, shopping-cart, giftcertificates

I'm doing some work on an existing site that uses Cartthrob and finishing off the gift certificate integration.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to show the details of a gift certificate that the customer is purchasing.

The certificate is a single "product" that can have a variable value which is selected when the customer adds it to their cart.

In the cart/checkout, I can show the product title and its price but I can't show the email address or message associated with the certificate.

There *has* to be a way to do that right?

Comment: Can you add sample code here of how you're storing those details with the product when adding it to the cart? Is it possible you have a syntax error there?

Answer (score 0):

Entirely depends on how the data was added to the order.

If you're passing on the fly data, then check out the [Adding Custom Data to Purchased Items and Orders](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/adding_custom_data_to_purchased_items_and_orders/index.html) part of the docs, else if it's coming from a products channel, then you can access the product details with the [{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/cart_items_info/index.html) tag.

Comment: The data is in the Cartthrob object (shown with {exp:cartthrob:debug_info} but is with "Meta" rather than custom options. I can't get it out of there.